# AVPlayer works on simulator but crashes on real device

Tags: swift, avplayer

AVPlayer is working fine in simulator but crashes on device.totally stuck please help out.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

let fileURL = NSURL(string:       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("introVideoURl") as! String)
playVideo(fileURL!) // crashing line

} 

 func playVideo(url: NSURL) throws-> AnyObject{

        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(introVideoController.playerDidFinishPlaying(_:)),
                                                         name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player.currentItem)
        player.play()
        return true

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("introVideoURl")` is not nil?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not nil

Comment: Show which line the device is crashing on

Comment: have edited check out

Comment: Looks like `fileURL` is nil. Please show us what is `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("introVideoURl")`.

Comment: @Thripthi Haridas you should use early exit statements.

Comment: @Nikunj can u explain

Comment: @kennytm i put a breakpoint. the value is not nil. working on simulator

Comment: use "guard let" which will give you 100% value. if it's nil further execution will be stopped.

Comment: have you tried after adding exceptional breakpoint. which will show you exact crash point.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Show the value